# how can we provide access for all authenticated users(basic authentication) in websphere for any role

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, authorization, websphere, wildfly

For Wildfly,any authenticated user can access to any protected resource by below change in web.xml

```
<auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

in security-constraint and defining security role as below

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

But the same is not working for Websphere, throwing authorisation failed exception, for making it work below change is required in Websphere Adminconsole.

1. WAS AdminConsole -> Applications > Enterprise Applications -> click .EAR
2. click the Security role to user/group mapping
3. Select the roles you wish to use for authentication.(in my case it is 
   *,defined in web.xml)
4. Map special subject to "All authenticated in Application Realm"

How can I skip the adminconsole change to make it work, or any other better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For achieving the above goal i.e authorization for all authenticated users in WebSphere, create one logical Role[No need to create any physical group] say "AllAuthneticated" in web.xml and provide it as authorization constrain.

> ```
>  <auth-constraint>
>       <role-name>AllAuthneticated</role-name>
>  </auth-constraint>
>
>
> <security-role>
>     <role-name>AllAuthneticated</role-name>
> </security-role>
> ```

And then define an ibm-application-bnd.xml in  EAR File as follows:

> ```
> <security-role name="AllAuthneticated">
>          <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
> </security-role>
> ```

The above role mapping will allow all authenticated user to access protected resource.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is that I define the ff in my **web.xml**:

```
<security-role>
  role1
</security-role>

<security-role>
  role2
</security-role>

     <security-constraint>
        <display-name>All Authenticated</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>
                All Authenticated Pages
            </web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/webpage.xhtml</url-pattern> 
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>role1</role-name>
            <role-name>role2</role-name> 
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Essentially this defines the roles and then a separate definition for the pages and the roles that will be permitted to access it.

And then I also define an **ibm-application-bnd.xml** in my EAR File as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

    <security-role name="role1">
        <group name="role1" />
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="role2">
        <group name="role2" />
    </security-role> 
</application-bnd>
```

This one I think WebSphere uses to map to its grouping your defined roles.

Hope this helps or puts you forward.